# Uglify Remove console.log.bind with pure_funcs

Tags: javascript, uglifyjs, terser

I am trying to optimize out binded `console.log` statements in minified js. I am binding `console.log` so that I can have an argument prepended by default.

The `pure_funcs` setting of uglifyjs doesn't appear to work (see output below)

`drop_console` is even worse because it sets `this.log = void` and causes undefined function errors.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Input:

```
class A {
    constructor() {
        this.log = console.log.bind(this, 'class A');
    }

    meth() {
        this.log('not optimized out');
        console.log('optimized out');
    }
}
```

UglifyJS config:

```
 drop_console     : false,
 pure_funcs       : ["console.log", "console.log.prototype.bind", "console.log.bind"],
```

Uglified (via https://skalman.github.io/UglifyJS-online/):

```
class A{constructor(){this.log=console.log.bind(this,"class A")}meth(){this.log("not optimized out")}}:
```

Comment: Does adding `this.log` to `pure_funcs` helps?

Comment: Yes, forgot to mention I tried that and it works, but of course isn't ideal.

Comment: Yes! using `this.*` for `pure_funcs` is actually a bad idea... But I'm curious, how would you use `A->.log`, Since it's an instance method of `A` how would you (_uniformly_) call the `A->log()` method outside `A`?

Comment: this.log is a private method, only used inside A, and each class I use has it's equivalent (with a different string prefix).